# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

This my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.howietian.jianshi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.ashokvarma.android:bottom-navigation-bar:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:30.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:30.0.3'
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'org.kie.modules:com-google-code-gson:6.5.0.Final'
    implementation files('libs/iTextpdf.jar')
}
```

can you please help me?

Comment: `28.0.0` is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate your support libraries to androidx.

You can find artifact mappings here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

And here is the androidx migration doc: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate